# Question about limiting distribution for standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

I am studying CLT and meet a question but I have no idea how to solve it, 
could you please show me how to prove this question (b)?

Thank you so much!
Wang

[image: Question picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for (b):

- In this case you can separate the sum into $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Z_i}{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac1n}{\sqrt{n}}$
- Since the $Z_i$ have independent normal distributions, you should be able to state the distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Z_i$ and so of $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Z_i}{\sqrt{n}}$, and thus find the distribution to which this converges in the limit
- $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac1n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not random, so you can calculate it (noting that the sum is over $i$ not $n$), and so you can find the value to which this converges in the limit
- Finally you can combine these to find the limiting distribution of  $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(Z_i+\frac1n\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!

Comment: Hi, more questiones. I can clearly get the first part of the summation as standard normal distribution. But how can I get the value of  the second part of the summation. And how can I combine the standard normal distribution and then get the new distribution? Thanks!

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac1n = n\cdot \frac1n=1$ so $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac1n}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and this tends to $0$ as $n$ increases, so you will be adding $0$ to a standard normal

Answer (score 0):

(a) $P(|1/n\sum (X_i-p_i)|>\epsilon)\leq 1/(n^2\epsilon^2)Var(\sum X_i)=1/(n^2\epsilon^2)\sum p_i(1-p_i)\leq 1/(n^2\epsilon^2)\sum 1/4=\frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}\rightarrow 0.$
(b) $\sum (Z_i+1/n)\sim N(1,n)\Rightarrow 1/\sqrt{n}\sum (Z_i+1/n)\sim N(1/\sqrt{n},1)\Rightarrow1/\sqrt{n}\sum (Z_i+1/n)\rightarrow_d N(0,1)$

Comment: Thanks for your comment! And why 1/(n2ϵ2)∑pi(1−pi)≤1/(n2ϵ2)∑1/4? Where does this 1/4 come from? Thanks!

Comment: For $0<x<1$, $x(1-x)\leq 1/4.$

Comment: Ok, I understand now! Thanks!